# Share nbactions.xml or integrate it into Maven

Tags: maven, netbeans

I have a Maven project in NetBeans which consists of multiple subprojects (each has its own `pom.xml`) and a shared parent `pom.xml`.
Some of the subprojects are configured by a `nbactions.xml` so that I can run and debug them (with the nice run and debug buttons of NetBeans).
Since the `nbactions.xml` is only detected if it lies at the root of each executable subproject I have to copy it.

Is there any way to avoid copying the `nbactions.xml` into each subproject which I want to execute? Is there maybe a chance to include the `nbactions.xml` into the parent `pom.xml` as one can do with  options of `nb-configuration.xml` (e.g. `netbeans.hint.license` or `netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform`)?

Here is my `nbactions.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
    <action>
        <actionName>debug</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run@debug</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>run</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
</actions>
```

Comment: For me the key was the following goal:
`<goal>org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run</goal>`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure custom action mapper in *Tools -> Options -> Maven -> Execution -> Edit Global Custom Goal Definition*. But adding manually could be tiresome.

Alternatively, you can copy and paste  your `nbactions.xml` into NetBeansUserDir\config\Projects\org-netbeans-modules-maven\ directory.  Where the location of  *NetBeansUserDir* you can find at Help -> About. For 11.0 LTS it looks like:

```
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_231-b11
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1251; ru_RU (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.0
Cache directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.0
```

Full path would be:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.0\config\Projects\org-netbeans-modules-maven\
```

The `nbactions.xml` in the directory applies to **all** your projects it could be wise to define custom mappings. Otherwise, if you don't add the  CUSTOM- prefix to the actions in nbactions.xml then the file just overwrite run and debug actions for all projects.

If you add CUSTOM- then they will be visible in Global Definition dialog and  you can map these actions to some toolbars.

For example, changed nbactions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
    <action>
        <actionName>CUSTOM-debug</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run@debug</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>CUSTOM-run</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
</actions>
```

After that you can find it in Global Custom Goal Definition and configure toolbar buttons for the actions:

[image]

Comment: I like the ideas, but in this case I could not share it through Git, could I? Well, I could create a symbolic link in the NetBeansUserDir that points to the `nbactions.xml`.

Comment: Yes, I think it's better than just copying the file to the User Dir.  So in the parent project, you can keep one copy of nbactions.xml and use link to it.  In any case, it looks more like a workaround than a proper solution but should work.